# Laravel Collective Checkbox return null value from form

Tags: laravel-5.5, laravelcollective

I'm trying to figure out the collective's checkbox function.
Here are the code in the blade template:

```
{{ Form::model($record, ['route' => ['access_record.update', $record->id], 'method' => 'put']) }}  
    {{ Form::checkbox('IsApprove', 1, true) }}     
    {{ Form::submit() }}
    {{ Form::close() }}
```

as you see, I set up the checkbox named: IsApprove and give it the default value. However, I can not receive any value from pages.
Here are the codes in the controller's update function:

```
public function update(Request $request, $id)
{         
    $record = Accessrecord::find($id);
     print_r($request->toArray());
}
```

And there is nothing to print out.

How do I make the collective's checkbox retrieve value?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess I find out the answer. It seems my apache server got crush. After restart apache server, it fixed.